# Why is it obligatory to include name of the interface in the implementation of Compare method?

Tags: c#, interface

Why the code:

```
class Person {
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }


    private class SortByName : IComparer<Person> {
        int Compare(Person o1, Person o2) {//error
            return 0;
        }
    };


    public static IComparer SortByName() {
        return (IComparer)new SortByName();
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name + " " + Age;
    }
}
```

and I have to explicitly write:

```
int IComparer<Person>.Compare(Person o1, Person o2)
```

instead if just:

```
int Compare(Person o1, Person o2)
```

It should be quite clear that I implement method from `IComparer` interface.

Also can I somehow make this code shorter:

```
   private class SortByName : IComparer<Person> {
        int Compare(Person o1, Person o2) {//error
            return 0;
        }
    };


    public static IComparer SortByName() {
        return (IComparer)new SortByName();
    }
```

I know that in C# anonymous classes cannot implement interfaces but is there any way besides lambda to make it shorter?

Comment: Did you forget to make your method `public`? If you did, quickly deleting the question is probably a good idea :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the method public if you want to implicitly implement the interface. This code should work:

```
private class SortByName : IComparer<Person>
{
    public int Compare(Person o1, Person o2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, so was it some kind of precaution from the C# side to counteract accidentaly reducing method visibility?

Comment: Simply, interfaces specify the public contract of the class. All methods that implement the interface should be public.